# Разбить элементы вектора по парам

Tags: c++

Есть вектор `vector<vector<string> >kosz;`, В нем содержатся векторы с разным количеством элементов. Нужно разбить элементы каждого из векторов по парам, но при этом нужно перебрать все возможные варианты соединения, тоесть к примеру первый элемент со вторым - одна пара, первый с третьим - вторая пара, второй с третьим - еще одна пара, ну и тд. И так нужно перебрать все и посчитать количество одинаковых пар во всех векторах. Тоесть, к примеру есть вектор `kosz {{a,b,c,d}, {b,c,d}`. В результате должно получится примерно так:`{a,b} - 1 раз, {b,c} - 2 раза, {c,d} - 2 раза, {b,d} - 1 раз,`.... ну и в таком духе. Смог только придумать как разбить векторы по парам, но чтобы перебрать все варианты, так не выходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
map <string/string; int>  // ключ - пара строк
for v in vectors
    for i = 0; i< v.size - 1
        for j = i + 1; i < v.size
             map[v[i]+v[j]] ++
```

Это просто перебор всех возможных пар в каждом векторе с добавлением их в словарь. Если в словаре нет такого ключа -  добавить ключ со значением 1, иначе увеличить значение на 1.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<vector<string>> vectors = { { "a", "b", "c"},
                                       { "a", "b", "d"},
                                       { "a", "c", "d"},
                                       { "a", "b"}};
    map<pair<string, string>, int> dict;
    for (auto v: vectors) {
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size() - 1; i++) 
            for (int j = i + 1; j < v.size(); j++) {
                pair<string, string> p = { v[i], v[j] };
                if (dict.find(p) == dict.end())
                    dict[p] = 1;
                else
                    dict[p]++;
            }
    }
    map<pair<string, string>, int>::iterator it;
    for (it = dict.begin(); it != dict.end(); ++it)
        cout <<it->second<<"\n";  
    return 0;
}
```

Как пару строк (ключ) вывести, я что- то не пойму.
Вывод `{"a", "b"}` встречается три раза и т.д.)

```
3 2 2 1 1 1
```

Comment: если можно, добавьте пару комментариев, для лучшего понимания алгоритма

Comment: можете исправить свой код на рабочий? Извините может за наглость, просто не удается самому разобраться. Не пойму как в качестве ключа передавать сразу 2 строки

Comment: ваш ответ нашел полезным, натолкнул на мысль, но увы он не является решением

Comment: Как это не является решением? Код привёл, но я не специалист в C++.

Comment: спасибо вам огромное. Приходится писать на C++98, там блин ничего нормально не работает. Но смог удачно переделать ваш алгоритм. Огромная благодарность