# Объединить пару элементов из одного вектора с другим элементом

Tags: c++

Есть вектор `vector<vector<string> >kosz`, в котором хранятся векторы с разным количеством элементов. Есть еще один вектор `vector<vector<string> >pairs;`, в нем хранятся элементы из вектора `kosz`, но разбитые по парам по принципу из этого [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1135881/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC). Нужно создать еще один вектор, или же это может быть словарь, в который нужно поместить пару элементов из вектора `pairs` и еще один элемент из вектора `kosz`. То есть должно быть примерно так: `kosz {{a,b,c,d}, {b,c,d}`, `pairs{{a,b},{b,c}, {c,d}, {b,d}}` и словарь к примеру в котором будут хранится `{{a,b},{c}},{{a,b},{d}},{{b,c},d},{{b,c},a},{{c,d},a},{{c,d},b},{{b,d},c},{{b,d},c}` ну и в таком роде. Получается пара + третий элемент(причем нужно перебрать все возможные элементы, которые могут быть третьими(в пределах проверяемого вектора, за исключением пары элементов, которые уже в нем имеются)). Надеюсь понятно изложил. Начал пробовать, вот что получилось. В общем, ошибка в том что перебирает не все пары из вектора `pairs`, в котором хранятся уникальные пары слов и выбивает, что происходит стирание элементов, где-то за пределами вектора, не пойму почему так.

```
vector<vector<string> >kosz;// здесь хранятся все элементы, по описанию выше
vector<vector<string> >pairs; // вектор с уникальными парами из вектора kosz
vector<string>pairs_vec_all; // вектор, в котором храню все слова из другого вектора
    map<pair<string, string>, string> triple_combo;// это уже словарь, в котором хранятся все возможные комбинации
//заполняю вектор словами       
for (int i = 0; i < kosz.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < kosz[i].size(); j++)
            {
                cout << "push kosz[i][j]): " << kosz[i][j] << endl;
                pairs_vec_all.push_back(kosz[i][j]);
            }
            cout << "\n" << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < pairs.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
                 //если слова совпадают, то нужно стереть каждое
                        if (pairs[i][0] == pairs[i][1])
                        {
                            auto it = std::find(pairs_vec_all.begin(), pairs_vec_all.end(), pairs[i][0]);
                            auto pos = it - pairs_vec_all.begin();
                            auto iter = pairs_vec_all.end();
                            int pos1 = 0;
                            if (it != pairs_vec_all.end())
                            {
                                auto iter = std::find(pairs_vec_all.begin() + pos, pairs_vec_all.end(), pairs[i][1]);
                                auto pos1 = iter - pairs_vec_all.begin();
                            }
                            if (it != pairs_vec_all.end() || iter != pairs_vec_all.end())
                        {
                            pairs_vec_all.erase(pairs_vec_all.begin() + pos);
                            pairs_vec_all.erase(pairs_vec_all.begin() + pos1);
                            pairs_vec_all.resize(std::distance(pairs_vec_all.begin(), pairs_vec_all.end()));
                        }

                    }
                    else {
                        auto it = std::find(pairs_vec_all.begin(), pairs_vec_all.end(), pairs[i][0]);
                        auto pos = it - pairs_vec_all.begin();
                        auto iter = std::find(pairs_vec_all.begin(), pairs_vec_all.end(), pairs[i][1]);
                        auto pos1 = iter - pairs_vec_all.begin();
                    if (it != pairs_vec_all.end() || iter != pairs_vec_all.end())
                    {

                        cout << "pos: " << pos << endl;
                        cout << "pos1: " << pos1 << endl;
                        cout << "pairs: " << pairs[i][0] << ", " << pairs[i][1] << endl;
                        pairs_vec_all.erase(pairs_vec_all.begin() + pos);
                        pairs_vec_all.erase(pairs_vec_all.begin() + pos1);
                        pairs_vec_all.resize(std::distance(pairs_vec_all.begin(), pairs_vec_all.end()));
                    }
                }
                }
        for (auto it = pairs_vec_all.begin(); it != pairs_vec_all.end(); ++it) // вывод на экран
            cout << ' ' << *it;
        cout << "\n" << endl;
        pair<string, string> pr(pairs[i][0], pairs[i][1]);
        for (int i = 0; i < pairs_vec_all.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << "pr: " << pr.first << ", " << pr.second << ", pairs_vec_all: " << pairs_vec_all[i] << endl;
            triple_combo[pr] = pairs_vec_all[i]; // здесь формируются уже пары в словаре + третье слово
        }
        pairs_vec_all.clear();
        cout << "cleared... " << pairs_vec_all.size() << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: решать лень, przepraszam, но могу дать ценный совет - разбить сложную задачу на несколько локальных простых подзадач и написать маленькие простые функции, которые решают каждую из подзадач, тогда решение сложной задачи покажется простым

Comment: @asianirish, знаю, примерно так и сделал, это уже один из последних блоков задачи

Comment: `//если слова совпадают, то нужно стереть каждое` - этого нет в описании задачи

Answer (score 2):

Ох, если я правильно понял то, что твориться в Вашем коде, то Вам нужно собрать все уникальные сочетания пар из вектора пар `pairs` и всех **строк** из `kosz` (далее `data`) и без повторов строк в кортеже. Я позволил себе использовать `std::vector<std::pair...>>` для вектора пар:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

auto tripleCombo(const std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> &data,
                 const std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> &pairs)
{
    std::unordered_set<std::pair<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, std::string>> result;
    for (const auto &strings : data) {
        for (const auto &item : strings) {
            for (const auto &pair : pairs) {
                if (pair.first != item && pair.second != item)
                    result.emplace(pair, item);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Если ожидается, что `data` содержит много повторов, то можно сделать предобработку `data` - переложить всё в `std::unordered_set<std::string>`.

PS: Если у вас ещё нет вычисления хеша от `std::pair`, придётся добавить, либо использовать простой `set`:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
struct std::hash<std::pair<A, B>>
{
    std::size_t operator()(const std::pair<A, B> &value) const noexcept
    {
        return std::hash<A>{}(value.first) ^ (std::hash<B>{}(value.second) << 1); // or use boost::hash_combine
    }
};
```

Comment: Для `emplace` `std::make_pair` не нужен, в этом же и смысл его