# удалить элементы из вектора

Tags: c++

Задача состоит в следующем: нахожу 2 нужных мне элемента в векторе и удаляю, но что-то не все так просто оказалось.

```
                    auto it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), pairs[i][0]);
                    auto pos = it - v.begin();
                    auto iter = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), pairs[i][1]);
                    auto pos1 = iter - v.begin();
```

Вычислил позицию нужных мне элементов, а затем стираю их из вектора:

```
                    v.erase(v.begin() + pos);
                    v.erase(v.begin() + pos1);
                    v.resize(std::distance(v.begin(), v.end()));
```

При этом выхожу бывает за пределы вектора, так как после удаления элемента, меняется размер вектора, если я не ошибаюсь. Как решить эту проблему? Вычислять позицию второго элемента после того как удалю первый - не вариант.

Comment: "*Вычислять позицию второго элемента после того как удалю первый - не вариант.*" Почему? И, кстати, зачем `erase` по позиции, а не сразу по итератору? Да, и еще - вот это - `v.resize(std::distance(v.begin(), v.end()));` - просто не имеет никакого смысла...

Comment: Вроде документацию читал, там было мол стирает значение, но место остается и нужно `resize` делать

Comment: @Harry, не имеет смысла потому что сначала проверяю, есть ли вообще эти два элемента в векторе, а только потом стираю. Тоесть получается сначала вычисляю позицию... Или же можно вычислять еще 3й раз, но думал может можно без этого

Comment: Это `remove` переносит, не удаляя. Как *точно* формулируется условие? Удалить все элементы, равные `a` или `b`, удалить только одну пару `a` и `b`, удалять только если есть и `a`, и `b`. Дайте **точное** задание, от этого зависит решение.

Comment: Для вашего случая простейший совет - удаляйте сначала дальний элемент, с большей позицией...

Comment: @Harry, кстати на счет дальнего элемента это гениальная идея, как только не догадался. Задание звучит так: если в векторе есть пара `a,b`, то мы их удаляем, если нету, то ничего не трогаем. И так нужно перебирать все пары во всех векторах. Вообще это маленький фрагмент из другого [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1136586), нашел пока что в этой части ошибка у меня.