# посчитать количество повторений одинаковых элементов в map

Tags: c++

Есть словарь `map<pair<string, string>, string> triple_combo`. Как посчитать количество повторений  одинаковых в нем элементов? Одинаковые элементы, это я имею ввиду в соответствии ключ - значение, ключ -значение и тд. Сколько раз эти пары повторяются?

Comment: Используйте `std::set`, добавив туда все элементы `map`. Ответом будет являться размер этого множества.

Comment: @Dareten, ага вы все верно подсказали, немного не правильно написал вопрос. Интересует количество повторений одинаковых элементов

Comment: Какие *одинаковые* элементы (ключи) в `map`?! Все ключи в нем различны по определению...

Comment: Может имелось в виду multimap ?

Comment: @Harry действительно забыл про это, добавлял несколько раз одинаковые элементы, думая что они там сохранятся

Comment: @DSuhoi действительно `multimp` будет использовать лучше, так как с `map` это ошибка получается. Но все же вопрос тот, как в том же `multimap` посчитать?

Answer (score 1):

По всей видимости, вопрос является следствием предыдущих Ваших вопросов: [Объединить пару элементов из одного вектора с другим элементом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1136586/214732) и [Разбить элементы вектора по парам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1135881/214732)

Фактически, Вам нужна гистограмма пар от пары строк и строки  `std::pair<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, std::string>` (либо это всё можно запихать в массив строк или [кортеж](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)). То есть:

```
std::map<std::pair<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, std::string>, int> histogramm;
...
++histogramm[std::make_pair(pair, item)];
```

Просто замените `set` на `map` в [моём ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1139589/214732)

Comment: да, вопрос является следствием. Уже решил те предыдущие вопросы сам, остался только этот. Видимо забыл что в словаре все значения уникальны и добавлял туда несколько раз одинаковые значения, думая, что они там сохранятся

Comment: думаю самым оптимальным вариантом, будет проверять, есть ли такое значение в `map` и если оно есть, то увеличивать счетик где-то в еще одном словаре, добавляя туда сразу пару + строка + счетик.... Хотя звучит это все как-то запутано

Comment: @Alex, если у Вас есть ответы на собственные вопросы и они лучше предложенных - напишите и отметте как принятый.

Answer (score 0):

Воспользовался ответом @MBo в другом вопросе. По сути, посчитать просто, но для этого пришлось изменить словарь, сделав `<pair<string, string>, string>` ключом и добавив словарь еще и значение в виде `int`, куда записывало количество повторений.

```
p = make_tuple(pair, string)

if (triple_combo.find(p) == triple_combo.end())
                    triple_combo[p] = 1;
                else
                    triple_combo[p]++;
```